# Error loading MySQLdb module: python3.5 + Django + mysqlclient OSX

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I have some problem. I try to connect my Django project with mysqldb. 
I use python3.5 + Django + OSX.
When i install python package mysqlclient (pip3 install mysqclient) and starting my project i get error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb 
module: dlopen(/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-35m-
darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
```

What does it mean? How can i fix this error.
I try to reinstall mysqlclient, update mysql - nothing helps.

Comment: can you post your settings code?

Comment: Please also include what version of OSX you're on, and how you installed MySQL (source? homebrew?). Thanks!

Comment: @FlipperPA i use MySQL 5.7.18 Homebrew DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

Comment: Python 3.6, Django 1.11, OSX Sierra 10.12.3

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb does not support Python 3. Fortunately, there are other engines you can use. Please see here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

I would recommend `mysqlclient`, which is a drop-in replacement for MySQLdb:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

Good luck!

Comment: All right. I use mysqlclient, but they dont working. He sent me error: Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows